# Passing an element of a function to a function in MATLAB

Tags: function, matlab, parameter-passing

I know that "passing a function to a function" topic is well defined, my question is slightly different.

I have the following function:

```
function P = function1(x)

a = x^2; b = 1/x;
c = x^3; d = sqrt(x);

P = [a b; c d]; % they are all functions of x

end
```

In a for loop, I would like to pass certain elements of the output `function1` to `function2` to be evaluated inside of it, as below:

```
for i=1:2
   for j=1:2
      A = function1(a);
      B = function2(A(i,j));
   end
end
```

However, my evaluation of function1 at `a` (not to be confused with `a` in `function1`) would have to be done in `function2`. In other words, I want to send output element (`i`,`j`) of my `function1` to `function2`, to be evaluated at a certain value `a` defined in `function2`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Note: One way of doing this is to send `i` and `j` information to `function2` along with `function1`. Then evaluate `function1` inside of `function2` and use `i` and `j` to extract the element I need. The solution I seek is not this but rather sending directly element (`i`,`j`) of `function1` output to be evaluated at `function2`.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your question. What are `[a b; c d]`? Are these functions, or are these values? I think a [mre] would be beneficial here.

Comment: They are functions of x, evaluated in function 1. I will edit the post accordingly with a simple example there.

Comment: what is wrong with the for loop in your implementation?

Comment: I want function2 to evaluate the i, j th component of function1 at a particular point, defined in function2.

Answer (score 2):

You can have `function1` return function handles, rather than computing values. We can't create an array of function handles, but we can create a cell array holding function handles. It would look like this:

```matlab
A = function1;
B = function2(A{i,j}, a);

function P = function1
a = @(x) x^2;
b = @(x) 1/x;
c = @(x) x^3;
d = @(x) sqrt(x);
P = {a b; c d};
end
```

Comment: That worked perfectly well for my case. Thank you very much.